# Value of uint32_t variable

Tags: c++, bit

```
uint32_t number = 00000000000000000000000000001011;
std::cout << number;
```

Why is the number's value 521 here?

Comment: because `0` at the beginning means octal, 1011 in octal is 521 in decimal

Comment: You may be interested in the `0b` prefix

Answer (score 2):

Number literals starting with a zero are interpreted as octal numbers (base 8).
1011 in base 8 is 521.

Comment: Surely a canonical exists for this?

Comment: Yes, sort of; constants that begin with "0x" are hexadecimal, and constants that begin with "0b" are binary; if there's only a 0 followed by more octal digits it is, indeed, octal.

Comment: 1011 in base 8 is not 512. It is 521.